# Add custom block below cart summary page magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout

Dears,

How can I add my custom block to cart summary page? I checked the `checkout_cart_index.xml` file but couldn't find exact location so could you guys provide me any solution?

[image]
Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below code to `app/design/frontend/Themename/Themedirectory/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml` file

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.content.block" after="-" template="Magento_Checkout::custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I have tried this in my local and it's looking like this - https://prnt.sc/mbvoxm

Please check with clear your cache.

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code to your custom theme layout or custom module layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.items">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.countdown" after="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Magento_Checkout::yourcustomeTemplate"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```